# Architecture for Semantic Web Framework

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, web-architecture

I am doing a project on Web Based Ontology for E-citizenship where a ".owl" file will be generated using Protege OWL editor. We have to use that file for enabling Web service. Can anyone suggest me the Web Architecture which I should follow for my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite what you're looking for, but [this](http://web2py.com/semantic) may give you some ideas (see [documentation](http://web2py.com/semantic/static/semantic.pdf)).